# add_action and wp_head not display content in head section

Tags: actions, wp-head

I have a big problem.
In a Wordpress page I've a function that generate og meta tags. I want to "append" that generated meta in the head section. So, I write this code:

```
add_action('wp_head', '_set_meta_tag');
function _set_meta_tag()
{
    global $nome;
    global $descr;
    global $file;
    global $path_meta;

    $output = "";
    $output .= '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$nome.'" />';
    $output .= '<meta property="og:type" content="article" />';
    $output .= '<meta property="og:image" content="'; $output .= get_bloginfo('template_url'); $output .= '/includes/img/immagini_evento/'.$file.'" />';
    $output .= '<meta property="og:url" content="'.$path_meta.'" />';
    $output .= '<meta property="og:description" content="'.truncate(htmlentities($descr),200).'" />';
    $output .= '<meta property="og:site_name" content="'; $output .= get_bloginfo('name'); $output .='" />';

    echo $output;}
```

`add_action('wp_head', '_set_meta_tag');` not display `$output`. Why?

I've prooved also to echoes a simple "hello world", but nothing happened!

Comment: did you ever solve this?  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code must run before the `wp_head` hook fires or nothing will happen, and when tested in a mu-plugin file it does work.

I suspect that you are trying to hook that function too late-- perhaps from inside a theme template file after [`get_header`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) (in most cases). Place that code in the theme's `functions.php` or in a (mu-)plugin file and it should work at least insofar as echoing content goes. I did not analyze it for other bugs.

Comment: Indeed, I try to hook this function in a template page :) Thanks! I will try to change tomorrow and let you now as soon as possible.

Comment: Any code that this code depends upon has to run before this code, obviously, so hook that code to `wp_head` as well or earlier. If this only has to run on one template you can probably put all of your code before `get_header` in the template file but my guess is that that won't work in your case-- that it needs to run more globally than that.

Comment: If I place in `functions.php`, can I extract a parameter with `get_query_var('id')` in order to generate after in that function a MySql query through id?

Comment: `get_query_var` depends on the `global` `$wp_query` object, so "Yes", probably.

Comment: It works, but Facebook Like Button not display the correct content. If I paste URL on Facebook, I see the correct content but If I click on the Like Button, the content is wrong.

Comment: "The content is wrong" is a pretty much meaningless description and without code there is not much else I can say.

Comment: I've solved. The problem was Facebook cache :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I solved the problem by creating my own hook.

This is in my `header.php` file. My hook is placed before `wp_head()`

```
<?php my_doc_head(); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

This hook and the callback function added to the hook are defined in my `function.php`.

```
function my_doc_head() {
    do_action('my_doc_head');
}

add_action('my_doc_head','my_seo_meta');
function my_seo_meta() {
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    //insert whatever code to build $output 
    echo $output;
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not make any sense! Would you like to explain why `wp_head` does not work and your custom hook works ?

Comment: I would love to explain it but I am not experienced enough and do not understand WordPress well enough to explain it.  All I know is, my function added as an action to wp_head() did not work.  In my research , I found this post,  read what s_ha_dum said and thought "maybe that's why I can't get my function to work, it isn't firing soon enough".  So I created my action and inserted it before wp_head() and voila!  Maybe it helps to know my function gets data from custom fields and inserts it into the document head (not the WordPress header).